# Error when trying to mock third party library in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm running into the following error when doing `jest.Mock` on a third party library. The library in question is `react-email-editor`.

```
jest.mock("react-email-editor", () => {
    return {
        Editor: <div>Email Editor</div>,
    };
});
```

Error with `jest.mock`

```
    file.js: babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: React
    Whitelisted objects: Array, ArrayBuffer, Boolean, DataView, Date, Error, EvalError, Float32Array, Float64Array, Function, Generator, GeneratorFunction, Infinity, Int16Array, Int32Array, Int8Array, InternalError, Intl, JSON, Map, Math, NaN, Number, Object, Promise, Proxy, RangeError, ReferenceError, Reflect, RegExp, Set, String, Symbol, SyntaxError, TypeError, URIError, Uint16Array, Uint32Array, Uint8Array, Uint8ClampedArray, WeakMap, WeakSet, arguments, expect, jest, require, undefined, console, DTRACE_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION, DTRACE_NET_STREAM_END, DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST, DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE, DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST, DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE, COUNTER_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION, COUNTER_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION_CLOSE, COUNTER_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST, COUNTER_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE, COUNTER_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST, COUNTER_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE, global, process, Buffer, clearImmediate, clearInterval, clearTimeout, setImmediate, setInterval, setTimeout.
    Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` are permitted.
```

And if I change it to`doMock` I get this:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Note: since I'm using Typescript and react email editor doesn't have type definitions, I had to create a stub definition file in my project root `.types/react-email-editor/index.d.ts` as follows:

`declare module "react-email-editor";`

Edit: List of imports before jest.mock is called

```
import { act, fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import * as React from "react";
import { EmailEditor, IEmailEditorProps } from "../EmailEditor"; // my wrapper around react-email-editor
import Editor from "react-email-editor";
```

Comment: Did you import `react-email-editor` in the test file?

Comment: I did like so `import Editor from "react-email-editor". I've read that due to `jest.mock` hoisting, the import has to come after the mock... I've tried that to but no luck.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the imports in the test leading up to the jest.mock call?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
jest.mock("react-email-editor", () => () => <div>Email Editor</div>);
```

Comment: Does it change if you do `import React from 'react'`?